# stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet seems to be deprecated in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

The following line of Swift 2 code

```
let newString = title.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

gives the following error

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet'

in Swift 4, Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 8):

It's actually not deprecated, just re structured in a swifty way .. Try this

```
let title = " Swift 4 white spaces.. he he "
let newString = title.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415462-trimmingcharacters)